# How to avoid the "Cannot delete from specified tables." in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, runtime-error, sql-delete

Here is the code that I am trying to run:

```
DELETE DISTINCTROW JHALL_REFERAL_ASSIGNMENTS.emp_id, JHALL_REFERAL_ASSIGNMENTS.ref_elem_id
FROM JHALL_REFERAL_ASSIGNMENTS
WHERE (((JHALL_REFERAL_ASSIGNMENTS.emp_id)=(select  b.emp_id from JHALL_REFERAL_ELEMENT a, JHALL_REFERAL_ASSIGNMENTS b, BSI_MARTS_D_EMPLOYEE c
    where C.FULL_NM = 'Employee'
    and A.REF_NAME ='Max Premium of 5,000'
    and A.REF_ELEM_ID = B.REF_ELEM_ID
    and B.emp_id = C.EMPLOYEE_KEY
)) AND ((JHALL_REFERAL_ASSIGNMENTS.ref_elem_id)=(select  a.ref_elem_id from   JHALL_REFERAL_ELEMENT a, JHALL_REFERAL_ASSIGNMENTS b, BSI_MARTS_D_EMPLOYEE c
    where C.FULL_NM = 'Employee'
    and A.REF_NAME ='Max Premium of 5,000'
    and A.REF_ELEM_ID = B.REF_ELEM_ID
    and B.emp_id = C.EMPLOYEE_KEY
  )));
```

Every time I try to run this in Access I get error 3086, "Cannot delete from specified tables." When trying to find information online I keep running into resolutions saying I should change the Unique Records field to "Yes" which I did but that did not solve my issue. I ran the same code (separating schema and table names with `.` instead of `_`) in Toad and it worked fine.

Comment: Is there any foreign key or constraint attached to any of those rows?

Comment: The employee_key, emp_id, and ref_elem_id are primary keys. Besides those there are no constraints.

Comment: Does any of your primary keys have relationships?

Comment: No, I didn't specify any relationships when developing it.

Comment: Is your primary key autonumbered?

Comment: Yeah, there are sequences generating the primary keys.

Comment: You need to set up the all the selection criteria as a derived table (subquery) and then use IN or NOT IN as appropriate.  I am fairly sure you won't be able to delete with that query. So `DELETE FROM Table WHERE ID IN (SELECT ..)`

Comment: That is how I tried to set it up the first time and still got the same error. I made a much simpler query for testing (DELETE * FROM JHALL_TEMP WHERE a = 1;) and got the same error so I'm fairly certain that the queries that I have been running aren't the issue (at least not the biggest one) but rather a setting somewhere in in access. Thanks for looking at my code though!

Answer (score 11):

I reviewed several posts, including this one, to muddle through a similar delete.  I used a query to distill the somewhat complex selection criteria down to a set of primary keys for the table targeted for record deletion.

I got the "Could not delete from specified tables" error and the "Specify the table containing the records you want to delete" error until I used:

```
delete distinctrow [Target_Table].* 
from [Target_Table] 
inner join [Criteria_Query] 
on [Criteria_Query].Index_PK = [Target_Table].Index_PK
where ( [Criteria_Query].Index_PK = [Target_Table].Index_PK )
;
```

This worked in Access 2013.

Answer (score 3):

This is really an infuriating problem as even the code below, quoted from above, results in a "Cannot delete from specified tables" error, if Criteria_Query is actually a query and not table.

```
delete distinctrow [Target_Table].* 
from [Target_Table] 
inner join [Criteria_Query] 
on [Criteria_Query].Index_PK = [Target_Table].Index_PK
where ( [Criteria_Query].Index_PK = [Target_Table].Index_PK )
;
```

the solution is to first select the results of `Criteria_Query` into a table, `tbl_Criteria_Query`, and then use the table in the `delete` statement:

```
select *
into [tbl_Criteria_Query] 
from [Criteria_Query]
;

delete distinctrow [Target_Table].* 
from [Target_Table] 
inner join [tbl_Criteria_Query] 
on [tbl_Criteria_Query].Index_PK = [Target_Table].Index_PK
;
```

Comment: I had no problem with Steve's answer, even with a two-table criteria query without unique records turned on. Anything else that might have affected this?

Comment: I encountered this and had to do this intermediary step as well. I think Access doesn't like using a non-updatable recordset in a JOIN on a DELETE. Another alternative, as described below, is to use a subselect in the where clause of the delete query, but in my experience this has been too slow to be useful once the delete-from table gets above a certain size (WHERE clause evaluated too many times)

Answer (score 3):

Select the IDs in a subquery and run delete on the table using in

```
Delete * from 
tbl_Delete

Where ID in (

Select id form table1
left join ..
left join ...

)
```

Comment: This is great, because it also works with subqueries. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just Run The Visual Studio (in Run As Administrator Mode).

Comment: Access usually does not have anything to do with VS, and Administrator permissions *definitely* won't help this at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when using an MS Access front end and SQL server back end.  I found that if I make my primary keys the same in SQL as in the local table in Access the problem was solved.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The following has worked for me `designview->propertysheet->General->set unique records to "yes"`